# How to get only last value of indicator in pine script

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

I am new to pine-script. Is there a way to get only last value of indicator in pine script?
Let's say I only want last value of exponential moving average of close
ema(close,21) through out the chart as a single horizontal line. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

To draw a dynamic horizontal line on the ema value use the built-in **line.new()** function and **line.set_*()** to update, as is shown below:

```
//@version=5
indicator("hline ema", overlay = true)

ema21 = ta.ema(close, 21)

var line l = line.new(bar_index, ema21, bar_index + 1, ema21, xloc.bar_index, extend.both, color.blue)

if barstate.isrealtime or barstate.islast
    line.set_xy1(l, bar_index, ema21)
    line.set_xy2(l, bar_index + 1, ema21)
```

[image]

Update:
Another way is to use the **plot()**'s **trackprice=** argument, use the additional **show_last=** argument to hide the main plot:

```
//@version=5
indicator("hline ema", overlay = true)
ema21 = ta.ema(close, 21)
plot(ema21, trackprice = true, show_last = 1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for reply. This will solve my problem but I wonder is there any other way other than use line-new function. I am familiar with metastock. There is a built-in function lastvalue() which shows only last value of an source. For example : MOV(close,21,E) draws actual ema  but when I use lastvalue(MOV(close,21,E)) Metastock draws only last value horizontally through out chart.

Comment: There is one more trick, updated the answer.